# nginx unknown directive when running in my VPS

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx, hexo

I have a problem when run nginx on my VPS (digital ocean,centOS)

It shows:

```
nginx: [emerg] unknown directive "[alert" in /usr/local/nginx/conf/wordpress.conf:14
```

wordpress.conf:

```
location / {
if (-f $request_filename/index.html){
                rewrite (.*) $1/index.html break;
        }
if (-f $request_filename/index.php){
                rewrite (.*) $1/index.php;
        }
if (!-f $request_filename){
                rewrite (.*) /index.php;
        }
}

[alert type="notice" close="true"]
rewrite /wp-admin$ $scheme://$host$uri/ permanent;

[/alert]
```

What is the problem?

Comment: there is no such thing as `[alert]` in nginx configs. What are you trying to do?

Comment: @Jerodev I was trying to config my server to run hexo, but somehow the nginx didn't work. I am a beginner.

Comment: at first remove `[alert type="notice" close="true"]
rewrite /wp-admin$ $scheme://$host$uri/ permanent;

[/alert]`

Comment: @j.d.  Dude, you are right. It works. :>

Answer (score 0):

Solved. Delete the

```
[alert type="notice" close="true"] rewrite /wp-admin$ $scheme://$host$uri/ permanent;
```

But I don't know why.

Comment: because nginx doesn't have  directive `alert ` :)